# Power BI - TopN + Others on data from two tables

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

I am a bit stuck with a specific case in Power BI. Let's say that we have two tables. The first one contains the product ID and the product name, and the second one contains the product ID and a specific budget.

I want to create a piechart showing the topN + group others. I have made a dax formula which works for data in a single table, but not on two.

Here is the formula :

```
ProductTop = 
VAR rankSiteImpressions = RANKX(ALL(Piechart); [Impressions ];;DESC)
return
IF(rankSiteImpressions<=3;Piechart[Site];"Others")
```

How can I apply this on data from two tables to get the top products by budget?

Many thanks,

Rémi

Comment: Do you have a correct relation between your tables?

Comment: Hi @Aldert, I do have a correct many to one relationship which is correctly working when displaying data from both tables.

Comment: I cannot get it to work either although the documentation states it is possible. To work around it, I propose first to create extra column on Table product where you summarize budgets and than rank them on otehr table.